# Typing text in Blazor input fields with Cypress doesn't work

Tags: razor, cypress, blazor

I have a simple web form built with Blazor, which I'm trying to test with Cypress. When I try to type text in a text field, the text is first inputted correctly, but after about a second it disappears from the screen. Similarly, if I select a value from a drop-down list, the correct value flashes on the screen and then disappears. Test passes and there are no errors or warnings in the console.

If I input text or do some other changes myself in the browser, everything works correctly. I can also correctly input text myself in the Cypress browser. The problem only occurs when Cypress is running the test.

This is a simplified version of my form in the .razor file, which can reproduce the problem. TempTableMapping is a simple object, which I use for binding the values.

```
<EditForm Context="formContext" Model="tempTableMapping">
    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-label-and-field">
            <label for="MappingName">Mapping name: </label>
            <InputText id="MappingName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="tempTableMapping.MappingName"></InputText>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

The Cypress code I use:

```
describe('My Test', function () {

    it('Type mapping name', function () {
        cy.visit('https://localhost:44374/mapping')
        cy.get('#MappingName').type("mapping_name")
    })
})
```

I think the problem might be related to some Javascript things that Blazor is doing in the background, but I don't know Blazor well enough to debug it further.

I have read this article (https://remibou.github.io/Test-a-Blazor-App-with-Cypress/) so it should be possible to use Cypress with Blazor. I also tried the polyfill-fix mentioned in the article, but it didn't help in this and isn't probably relevant to this issue. I also noticed the following issue (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4635), which might be related to this issue.

I am using Cypress version 3.7.0.

Comment: Did you try with `@bind-Value="@tempTableMapping.MappingName"` ?

Comment: I tried that now, but it didn't make a difference. Both ways seem to work and bind the value correctly to the object.

Comment: Is there something that set `tempTableMapping.MappingName` in your C# code ?

Comment: In the beginning of my @code block, I have initialized the object like this:

`TableMappingList tempTableMapping = new TableMappingList();`

MappingName is a string field and there is no other specific C# related to it. It is also working well when I'm using it myself in the browser, the problem occurs only when Cypress is using it.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I noticed that Selenium Webdriver manages to use the Blazor input fields correctly